# SwiftUI - All variables toggle instead of juts one

Tags: toggle, swiftui

I have 5 state variables and 5 button.
I want them in a row, and to toggle them one by one

Variables

```
@State private var canEat: Bool = false
@State private var canDrink: Bool = false
@State private var canSleep: Bool = false
@State private var canDance: Bool = false
@State private var canEntertain: Bool = false
```

Button

```
Section(header: Text("Action".uppercased())) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {self.canEat.toggle()}){Image("ToEat").foregroundColor(self.canEat ? .green : .red)}
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {self.canDrink.toggle()}){Image("ToDrink").foregroundColor(self.canDrink ? .green : .red)}
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {self.canSleep.toggle()}){Image("ToSleep").foregroundColor(self.canSleep ? .green : .red)}
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {self.canDance.toggle()}){Image("ToDance").foregroundColor(self.canDance ? .green : .red)}
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {self.canEntertain.toggle()}){Image("ToEntertain").foregroundColor(self.canEntertain ? .green : .red)}
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
```

The issue is when i toggle one, They all toggle together ...

If i create another VStack below and add an acxtual toggle

```
    VStack{
        Toggle(isOn: $canEat) {
            Image("ToEat")
        }
    }
```

then i'm able to toggle only one.

Idea why ? and how i could resolve this ?

THanks,
Nicolas

Comment: in latest Xcode, you can toggle each one separately

Comment: This is the version i use : Version 11.3 (11C29)
What's yours ?

Comment: same as yours version. There is no other container beyond the section

Comment: The section is in a Form : Form {}

Comment: I remove the form and it worked

Comment: Works ok with Xcode 11.2. I highly recommend to downgrade Xcode (probably even to 11.1), because too many broken areas are reported on SO in Xcode 11.3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `action` to a `TapGesture`.

```
        Form{
        Section(header: Text("Action".uppercased())) {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {}){Image("image").foregroundColor(self.canEat ? .green : .red)}.onTapGesture {
                    self.canEat.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}){Image("image").foregroundColor(self.canDrink ? .green : .red)}.onTapGesture {
                    self.canDrink.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}){Image("image").foregroundColor(self.canSleep ? .green : .red)}.onTapGesture {
                    self.canSleep.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}){Image("image").foregroundColor(self.canDance ? .green : .red)}.onTapGesture {
                    self.canDance.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}){Image("image").foregroundColor(self.canEntertain ? .green : .red)}.onTapGesture {
                    self.canEntertain.toggle()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
}
```